# complex conditions with do until

Tags: excel, vba

```
Do Until Selection.Value = "" Or _
     (Selection.Value = theyear And Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value = themonth)

Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop
```

in this line of statement, the code is unable to check the condition with the or part ie; it does not check the condition in the bracket. Is it expected?

Comment: The given code works as expected for me when I replace theYear and themonth with "A" and "B". It will exit the loop in case 1 of the two statements is true. Check carefully the values contained in theyear and themonth (locals window or debug.print).

Comment: theyear and themonth are taken through an inputbox as: themonth = InputBox("Enter the first three alphabets of the month to append", "Month Initials")

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference Dinesh. Did you check the conditions? Debug.print Selection.Value = theyear returns true / false? Somewhere something should not match. If you can upload the file I'm willing to take a look.

Comment: themonth = InputBox("Enter the first three alphabets of the month to append", "Month Initials")
theyear = InputBox("Enter the year to which the month corresponds", "Year")

Do Until Selection.Value = "" Or (Selection.Value = "theyear" And Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value = "themonth")
   Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Loop

this is the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()

Dim sMonth As String
Dim iYear As Integer

sMonth = UCase(Trim(InputBox("Enter the first three alphabets of the month to append", "Month Initials")))
iYear = InputBox("Enter the year to which the month corresponds", "Year")
Do Until Selection.Value = "" Or _
    (UCase(Trim(Selection.Value)) = sMonth And Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value = iYear)
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

End Sub
```

Your main mistake was to put a variable name between quotes. 
However, I want to make note that this code may be quite sensible to bugs due to the fact that you allow the user to input any data without check.
But if it's for own use, this doesn't really matter.
Also note that .Select/Offset makes your code overall pretty rigid.